# DAKOTA 6.1 unrecognized identifier 'template_directory'

Tags: optimization

I am getting the error:

```
unrecognized identifier 'template_directory'
```

when I launch the command

```
dakota -check dakota_of.in
```

I am using Dakota version 6.1; by looking at the dakota_of.in file reported below can you tell me what I am missing?

dakota_of.in file contents:

```
# Usage:
#   dakota -i dakota_of.in -o run.out > stdout.out

environment #strategy
   #graphics
    tabular_graphics_data
        tabular_graphics_file = 'table_out.dat'
    #single_method

model
 single  

method
   id_method = 'method1'     
    dace oa_lhs
        #POSSIBLE OPTIONS FOR DACE EXPERIMENT
        #box_behnken
        #central_composite
        #grid
        #lhs
        #oa_lhs
        #oas
        #random
    samples = 20
    seed = 52         

model
  single

variables,
  continuous_design = 2
   #cdv_initial_point     6.0    4.0 
    cdv_initial_point     4.0    6.0   
    cdv_lower_bounds      1.0    1.0  
   #cdv_upper_bounds      9.0    6.0
    cdv_upper_bounds      8.0    6.0
    cdv_descriptors       'x1'   'x2'



interface,
    fork
    asynchronous
      evaluation_concurrency = 4
      analysis_driver = 'simulator_script'
      parameters_file = 'params.in'
      results_file= 'results.out'
      work_directory directory_tag 
      template_directory = 'templatedir'
# more info from https://dakota.sandia.gov/sites/default/files/docs/6.0/html-ref/interface-analysis_drivers-fork-work_directory.html

# uncomment to leave params.in and results.out files in work_dir subdirectories
      named 'workdir' file_save  directory_save
      aprepro

## when using conmin_frcg (above) with analytic_gradients (below), 
## need to turn off the active set vector as rosenbrock_bb does not parse it.
      deactivate active_set_vector

responses,
  num_objective_functions = 1
  no_gradients
  no_hessians
```

Additional information: The code above was taken from a DAKOTA tutorial developed for DAKOTA version 5.4.0 (courtesy of [University of Genova Optimization Course with DAKOTA](http://www.dicat.unige.it/guerrero/dakotaof.html)). I just copied the files and tried to launch the [tutorial 4](http://www.dicat.unige.it/guerrero/opt/naca_shape.zip) using DAKOTA 6.1. Maybe some syntax input parameters has to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for work_directory has changed in newer versions of Dakota.  You can see the specific keywords for Dakota 6.1 here: https://dakota.sandia.gov//sites/default/files/docs/6.1/html-ref/interface-analysis_drivers-fork-work_directory.html.
Also some training material here: https://dakota.sandia.gov/sites/default/files/docs/training/201508/DakotaTraining_Interfacing.pdf, slide 28.

The short summary is you probably want something like:

```
    work_directory directory_tag    
    link_files = 'templatedir/*'
```

See examples here too: https://dakota.sandia.gov//sites/default/files/docs/6.1/html-ref/interface-analysis_drivers-fork-work_directory-link_files.html

[brian courtesy at sandia labs]